# getting a switch function to automatically render next component

Tags: reactjs

created a switch function, not able to automatically update app and re-render different component

I've setup a function to switch components based on state, and setup componentDidUpdate to re-render when the state changes. If you manually go in and switch the conditions within the function it will render a new component. I'm just not understanding how to get it to refresh itself?

```
  componentDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
       this.getComponent(nextState.weather, nextProps);
       console.log('city and country:' + this.state.city, 
       this.state.country);
      }

         Then this is the switch function
      getComponent(props = {} || this.props, state) {
        switch (this.state.weather) {
          case !this.fetchedweatherdata:
            return (
            <DisplayWeather
               currentweather={this.state.currentweather}
               currentforecast={this.state.currentforecast}
               currenttime={this.state.currenttime}
               />
             );

          case !this.hourlyWeather:
            return (
               <DisplayHourlyWeather hourlyWeather= 
                 {this.state.hourlyWeather} />
                 );

           case this.fetchedweatherdata:
              return (
                 <Form
                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                    {...this.state}
                    onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
                  />
                );

            default:
            return null;
            }
           }
```

I have a codepen up without the api key so you can generally see what is happening:
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-shtern-9m983

Comment: Your switch statement doesn't make any sense, I suggest you read a bit about how it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: Note also that `componentDidUpdate` gives you the _previous_ props and state, not the next. If you want `this.getComponent` to give you a result based on the current props+state, this will fail as a result.

Comment: What's more, you're calling `this.getComponent(nextState.weather, nextProps)` on update (and actually passing `(prevState.weather, prevProps)` as a result), but the method itself accepts `(props = {} || this.props, state)`, which doesn't line up. On top of this, you're not referencing either argument in the body of the function, using only `this.state` values.